# Jaxb cycle (infinite loop) marshalling error - MOXy and Spring OXM

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, moxy

I get a JAXB marshalling error (cycle infinite loop) - posted at end of this question.

I know it's due to a 2 way object reference and I have used EclipseLink MOXy JAXB marshaller in a test case to resolve this specifying ID and IDREF and specified the JAXB provider using a jaxb.properties file containing

```
javax.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
```

However the production code uses Spring OXM and I cannot see how to achieve a similar result using this.

I have added a jaxb.properties file but it isn't being used - I know this because I add an empty file as a test and it doesn't complain (like it did on the prototype test case).

How do I specify the JAXB marshaller to use?
It appears to be using:

```
org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.XMLMarshaller
```

whereas my working test case uses :

```
org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBMarshaller
```

Exception:
    javax.xml.bind.MarshalException
     - with linked exception:
    [Exception [EclipseLink-25037] (Eclipse Persistence Services -
    2.6.1.v20150916-55dc7c3):
    **org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.XMLMarshalException
    Exception Description: A cycle is detected in the object graph.  This will 
    cause an infinite loop:**
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBMarshaller.marshal 
    (JAXBMarshaller.java:487)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK - to resolve this I specified (in the Spring OXM file)

```
<xml-inverse-reference mapped-by="myObject" 
    <xml-element xml-idref="true"
```

I only added the xml-idref="true" relationship